# Recover data from iOS app that needs to be updated

Tags: ios, ipad, data

I have an app called Matcha that I’ve used for writing. I hadn’t opened it in a few months but when I tried tonight the message said the developer needs to update the app to work with this version of iOS. I have 14.6 but I don’t know when the last update was. The Matcha website seems to be unsupported; the blog link and support link don’t work. How do I get my data out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adam Engst of tidbits.com did this with the Momento Classic app using iExplorer to browse a backup of the device containing app data.

If you haven’t uninstalled the app yet, the data is still there. Make a Mac backup now and you can still get your data! The app is inaccessible but the data isn’t removed in case the developer released an update.

https://tidbits.com/2021/05/20/extracting-data-from-an-old-ios-app-broken-by-ios-14-5/

> Working with the backups got me thinking that perhaps I could extract the data from a recent backup of my iPhone 11 Pro.
>
> […]
>
> I downloaded the demo version of iExplorer, launched it, opened its Backup Explorer view, and did a search on "[app name]". That revealed Documents and Library folders.